# How to expand this SQL table on it self on Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a talbe showing number of errors pr month and department

```
Year    Month   Department  NumErrors
2022    1       Sales           9
2022    2       Sales           8
2022    3       Sales           6
2022    …       Sales           3
2022    12      Sales           9
2023    1       Sales           1
2023    …       Sales           2
2023    12      Sales           8
```

Want I want to end up with is the accumelated number of error over all span combinations months - be it jan-august or june-dec.

I hopeed to end up with something like this:

```
Year    Months      First Month Last Month  Department  NumErrorsSum
2022    1           1           1           Sales       9
2022    1,2         1           2           Sales       17
2022    1,2,3       1           3           Sales       23
2022    1,2,3,4     1           4           Sales       48
2022    2,3         2           3           Sales       14
2022    2,3,4,5     2           5           Sales       27
2023    6,7,8,9     6           9           Sales       36
```

Why though? I need to display this data in Power apps, and this is just a snippit of the data need to be computed and delegation in power apps causes problems.

Is this make sense. I've struggeled with this but my SQL skills are just not enough to solve this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific functionality will probably be used.)

Comment: Also show us your current attempt.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using power apps correctly...

Comment: What is your sql-server version? Since 2022 you can use GENERATE_SERIES relational operator.

Comment: Siting on a version 2019

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```sql
with cte_numbers as (
    select *
    from (
        values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    ) x (num)
)
select distinct year, string_agg(month, ',') within group(order by t.month) as months, department, SUM(numErrors)--, n.num, n2.num
from cte_numbers n
inner join cte_numbers n2
    ON  n2.num >= n.num
inner join
(
    VALUES  (2022, 1, N'Sales', 9)
    ,   (2022, 2, N'Sales', 8)
    ,   (2022, 3, N'Sales', 6)
    ,   (2022, 12, N'Sales', 9)
    ,   (2023, 1, N'Sales', 1)
    ,   (2023, 12, N'Sales', 8)
) t (Year,Month,Department,NumErrors)
    ON  t.month between n.num and n2.num
group by year, Department, n.num, n2.num
```

This generates sequences of months and then groups by it. DISTINCT is needed to remove some duplicate rows since your sample data contains holes.

Output:

| year | months | department | (column 4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | Sales | 9 |
| 2022 | 1,2 | Sales | 17 |
| 2022 | 1,2,3 | Sales | 23 |
| 2022 | 1,2,3,12 | Sales | 32 |
| 2022 | 12 | Sales | 9 |
| 2022 | 2 | Sales | 8 |
| 2022 | 2,3 | Sales | 14 |
| 2022 | 2,3,12 | Sales | 23 |
| 2022 | 3 | Sales | 6 |
| 2022 | 3,12 | Sales | 15 |
| 2023 | 1 | Sales | 1 |
| 2023 | 1,12 | Sales | 9 |
| 2023 | 12 | Sales | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table of spans you want and use it in your queries.

```
with months(m) as (
  select 1 union all 
  select 2 union all 
  select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all 
  select 5 union all 
  select 6 union all 
  select 7 union all 
  select 8 union all 
  select 9 union all 
  select 10 union all 
  select 11 union all 
  select 12)
select m1.m sm, m2.m em, string_agg(m3.m,',') mspan
into mspans
from months m1
join months m2 on m1.m<=m2.m
join months m3 on m3.m>=m1.m and m3.m<=m2.m
group by m1.m, m2.m;

select * 
from mspans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the cumulative months, the sum can be done using a window function

```sql
SELECT *,
  NumErrorsSum = SUM(NumErrors) OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY Month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM YourTable;
```

You could possibly generate the month numbers using a subquery from `GENERATE_SERIES`

```sql
SELECT *,
  AllMonths = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(g.value, ',')
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, t.Month) g
  ),
  NumErrorsSum = SUM(t.NumErrors) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Year ORDER BY t.Month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM YourTable t;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all combinations of Year, Department, and month-ranges, you will need to:

1. Generate all of the desired month range combinations (72 of them),
2. Build all list of all distinct year and department combinations,
3. Cross-join the above,
4. Left-join the combinations from 3 with your source data,
5. Group and aggregate the results.

The following uses several Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to pre-calculate the month ranges and distinct year/department combinations, and then pulls it all together in the final select.

```
;WITH CTE_Months AS (
    -- Months 1-12
    SELECT V.Month
    FROM (
        VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    ) V(Month)
), CTE_MonthRanges AS (
    -- All month ranges 1..1, 1..2, ... 1..12, ... 11..12, 12..12
    SELECT
        M1.Month AS FirstMonth,
        M2.Month AS LastMonth,
        STRING_AGG(M.Month, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY M.Month) AS Months
    FROM CTE_Months M1
    JOIN CTE_Months M2 ON M2.Month >= M1.Month
    JOIN CTE_Months M ON M.Month BETWEEN M1.Month AND M2.Month
    GROUP BY M1.Month, M2.Month
),
CTE_YearDepartment AS (
    -- Years and departments
    SELECT DISTINCT Year, Department
    FROM ErrorData
)
SELECT
    --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YD.Year, YD.Department, MR.FirstMonth, MR.LastMonth) AS RowNum,
    YD.Year, MR.Months, MR.FirstMonth, MR.LastMonth, YD.Department,
    ISNULL(SUM(ED.NumErrors), 0) as NumErrorsSum
FROM CTE_YearDepartment YD
CROSS JOIN CTE_MonthRanges MR
LEFT JOIN ErrorData ED
    ON ED.Year = YD.Year
    AND ED.Department = YD.Department
    AND ED.Month BETWEEN MR.FirstMonth AND MR.LastMonth
GROUP BY YD.Year, YD.Department, MR.Months, MR.FirstMonth, MR.LastMonth
ORDER BY YD.Year, YD.Department, MR.FirstMonth, MR.LastMonth
```

Partial results:

| Year | Months | FirstMonth | LastMonth | Department | NumErrorsSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Sales | 9 |
| 2022 | 1,2 | 1 | 2 | Sales | 17 |
| 2022 | 1,2,3 | 1 | 3 | Sales | 23 |
| 2022 | 1,2,3,4 | 1 | 4 | Sales | 26 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 | 1 | 12 | Sales | 35 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | 12 | 12 | 12 | Sales | 9 |
| 2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Sales | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023 | 6,7,8,9 | 6 | 9 | Sales | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023 | 12 | 12 | 12 | Sales | 8 |

(Note that the reference data was incomplete, so some of the above values do not match the expected results.)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GizLqI4o) for a demo that includes the full result set.

If a department has no error data for an entire year, that department/year will be excluded from the results. To include it (with all NumErrorsSum values = 0), you can calculate separate `DISTINCT Year` and `DISTINCT Department` sources and cross-join them in the final query.